# VLC Media Player and Youtube Playback jerky

Tags: sound, video, flash, vlc, youtube

I installed VLC Media Player 2.0.8 on my Ubuntu and I tried to play videos on youtube and VLC Media player they were jerky. The video stops and sound repeats again and again like a scratched VCD is being played. After 5-8 secs both audio and video restore to normal playback (for few minutes). After that, the same jerky playback for 5-8 secs and again normal playback. This happens randomly not at any particular time of video play. I am using mp4 format 1080p video.

Comment: Does this happen with lower quality videos too?

Comment: yes with all kinds of videos

Comment: while playback it showed this error:::::   Potential PulseAudio version problem:
PulseAudio is streaming with an excessive latency. Sound may be lost or quality degraded.
To address that issue, upgrade the PulseAudio daemon to version 3.0, or disable the alternate sampling rate in its configuration.